# Data not syncing from iPad2 to iPad1

Tags: ensembles

I have both iPads disconnected from the debugger, running "stand alone"... any changes I make on iPad 1 appear on iPad 2, but the reverse is not true (changes made on iPad2 do NOT show up on iPad 1).  I have checked the universal identifier and they are the same!

They (the two objects) are the same, hence they have the same global id's (universal identifiers); same SKU numbers, same global ids = same book.   The code is the same on iPad 2 as it is on iPad 1, but iPad 2's changes, deletes, etc don't show up on iPad 1.  I don't want to "clean" both devices, because this is something the user's would absolutely have fits about! :D

Where do I start looking for the cause?

Comment: Are both devices connected to iCloud Drive? You can't sync iCloud Drive to the old iCloud Documents system. The two don't mix.

Comment: iCloud Drive is on, on both iPads and the iCloud storage used, as shown by both devices is the same amount.

Comment: So I decided to run the Magical Record sample;  same exact issue: I can change the number on iPad1 and it shows up in iPad2, but when I change the number on iPad2, nothing happens!  Therefore, I believe it's in the device, but since I have only 1 other device to test on, I think I'm screwed (especially it belongs to my wife!).  Any ideas?

Comment: Here's the verbose log from the Ensembles MR test between iPad1 and 2...    https://spaces.hightail.com/space/3iM8e

Comment: The logs look fine. I can see the new event generated and added to iCloud on iPad2. So I suspect iCloud is just being temperamental about transferring that new file back to iPad1. It an sometimes take a while. You can sometimes get a device to start transferring by doing a reset (hold on/off and home in until you see the apple icon). But it all looks good in the logs at least.

Comment: Unbelievable!  I installed iOS 9.2.1, had to *re-initialize iCloud*, and it's now working as it should!  Go figure!